# How to remove -r-00000 from part-r-00000 in reducer output

Tags: java, hadoop2

In my MapReduce code, in the reducer side I am implementing `MultipleOutputs` and I have attached inputsplit to it. I want my output file name as my keyvalue and not as `keyvalue-r-00000`. How can I remove the trailing value. Here is my code in reducer side.

```
String last = map.lastKey();
        String tab2[] = last.split(",");
        String line1 = "[" + tab2[2] + "," + tab2[3] + "," + tab2[8] + "]" + "\n" + "];";
        text1.set(line1);
        multipleOutputs.write(NullWritable.get(), text1, generateFileName(key));
    }

    String generateFileName(Text key){
        return key.toString();      
    }

    @Override
    public void setup(Context con){
        multipleOutputs = new MultipleOutputs<NullWritable, Text>(con);
    }

    @Override
    public void cleanup(final Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException{
        multipleOutputs.close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As per [Javadoc of MultipleOutputs](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.4.1/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/output/MultipleOutputs.html) the parameters are as follow

```
write(KEYOUT key, VALUEOUT value, String baseOutputPath)
```

here your first parameter should be key

so it would be

```
multipleOutputs.write(key, text1, generateFileName(key));
```

It is working for me.

Comment: Its working for me as well. If my key is FileName, then my output is FileName-r-00000. But, I dont want the -r-00000 extension.